# How can I remove an entire sentence that has a number, special character, website url, or email?

Tags: python, regex

How can I remove an entire sentence that has a number, special character, website url, or email?

Sample input Option A:

```
['Hi my name is blank.', 'Do it 3 times.', 'Check out this website: https://blah.com', 'I like pie.', 'My email is asdf@jkl@gmail.com.']
```

Sample input Option B:

```
['Hi my name is blank. Do it 3 times. Check out this website: https://blah.com', 'I like pie. My email is asdf@jkl@gmail.com.]
```

Sample output:

```
['Hi my name is blank.','I like pie']
```

Current code:

```
def remove_emails(self, dataframe):
    self.log.info('Removing emails from text data')
    no_emails = dataframe.str.replace('\S*@\S*\s?', '')
    return no_emails

def remove_website_links(self, dataframe):
    self.log.info('Removing website links from text data')
    no_website_links = dataframe.str.replace('http\S+', '')
    return no_website_links

def remove_special_characters(self, dataframe):
    self.log.info('Removing special characters from text data')
    no_special_characters = dataframe.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', regex=True)
    return no_special_characters

def remove_numbers(self, dataframe):
    self.log.info('Removing numbers from text data')
    no_numbers = dataframe.str.replace('\d+', '')
    return no_numbers
```

The problem is the above code can be used to replace the unwanted strings with an empty string, but I don't know how to remove an entire list element if it matches any of the regexes given above. I would prefer not to run through the list multiple times for each of these sentence extractions as well. Overall, I'm removing "bad" sentences from my corpus.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Alderven Added clarification in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check various cases using this regex and reject the string that matches it.

```
https?:|@\w+|\d
```

Python codes,

```
import re

arr = ['Hi my name is blank.', 'Do it 3 times.', 'Check out this website: https://blah.com', 'I like pie', 'My email is asdf@jkl@gmail.com']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'https?:|@\w+|\d',s)
 if (m):
  pass
 else:
  print(s)
```

Results in only sentences you want,

```
Hi my name is blank.
I like pie
```